# Как продавать бота, которому нужен логин-пароль?

Tags: безопасность, юридические-аспекты

Имеется комплекс ботов для одного сайта, который разными способами делает заданный аккаунт популярнее.

Бот будет продаваться двумя способами - SaaS (услуга ботов в облаке) за дешево, и в руки за дорого.

Есть проблема: бот работает не через API (которое не все возможности дает вообще), а имитирует браузер. Поэтому ему нужны логин и пароль от раскручиваемого акка.

В лучшем случае (наверно) можно сменить пароль на 30 сек, сообщить мне, я авторизую ботов, отпишу, тогда можно снова сменить пароль, а боты будут работать долгие дни.

Но все равно вангую, что многие будут бояться.

**Как внушить доверие хотя бы при покупке бота? Есть ли сервисы, где могут проверить exe и выдать официальный сертификат за деньги?**

Comment: Можно заказать аудит, но придется открыть исходники.

Comment: @free_ze А как доказать что собран тот код?

Comment: открыть исходники)

Comment: @free_ze клиенты ж не будут ставить VS, собирать и проверять

Comment: им никто не будет мешать это сделать. Open source так и живет.

Comment: Боюсь, бинарники аудировать будет стоить столько, что вам не захочется. Тем более, что это нужно под каждую сборку каждой версии.

Comment: @free_ze Одна версия только и бинарник .netовский и сниффер никто не отменил и не дорог тут сам труд реверсера, но реверсер ВасяПупкинСЕкзелаба не имеет авторитета. авторитет - это GlobalSign, Symantec...

Comment: Ах, ну дотнетовский байткод - это отдельная тема) Сниффер не поможет по той причине, что процесс может управляться извне

Comment: @free_ze Все равно он увидит все непонятное. Даже если это просто TCP/UDP-подключение к левому серваку, все равно подозрительно. У меня и такого нет.